# Firebase Auth photoURL always returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Trying to follow the Firebase doc to update the photoURL of users. However, when I update, it only returns null.

```
editProfilePicture(){
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    user.updateProfile({
      displayName: "Jane Q. User",
      photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
    }).then(function() {
      // Update successful.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
  }
```

I render the image using a component that takes the return of photoURL `<ProfilePicture image={currentUser && currentUser.photoURL} />`.

currentUser is `const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()`, and this works perfect for `displayName`..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code looks perfectly fine. Could you try to add the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged to see if maybe you are just using an old reference? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: which auth provider are you using?

Answer (score 3):

if you using google auth it will works fine but if you using just email and password auth it couldn't return the user profil(null) because you just initialize email and password by your own, your app just borrow your email.

Comment: so can we get its photourl at the time of signup?